# Analyzer in Solr QueryParserPlugin

Tags: solr

I've written a QueryParser that is looks a little like Lucene's `QueryParser`. I've written a simple `QParser` and a `QParserPlugin` with which I can use my QueryParser.

*One question that remains is:* Where do I get a reference to the `Analyzer` configured in the Solr schema? Or how can I inject it to use the Analyzer into my query parser's [constructor](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html#QueryParser%28org.apache.lucene.util.Version,%20java.lang.String,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer%29)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my (simplified) solution in Java for using the configured Analyzer (and default field) from the schema file in `MyQueryParser`.

```
public class MyParserPlugin extends QParserPlugin {
    @Override
    public QParser createParser(String qstr, SolrParams localParams, SolrParams params, SolrQueryRequest req) {
        return new MyQParser(qstr, localParams, params, req);
    }
}

class MyQParser extends QParser {
    public MyQParser(String qstr, SolrParams localParams, SolrParams params, SolrQueryRequest req) {
        super(qstr, localParams, params, req);
    }

    @Override
    public Query parse() throws ParseException {
        // Getting info from the schema
        String field = this.getReq().getSchema().getDefaultSearchFieldName();
        Analyzer analyzer = this.getReq().getSchema().getQueryAnalyzer();

        // Here we go
        MyQueryParser parser = new MyQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, field, analyzer);
        return parser.parse(this.qstr);
    }
}
```